# LibGit2Sharp blob.GetContentText() does not return \r

Tags: c#, git, repository, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I tried to get a file from the repository.

```
blob.GetContentText()
```

This file conatins "\r". It seems to me that LibGit2Sharp removes this character.
Is there a possibility to get the real content without any changes?

**Update1**
I have this content inside a textfile:

```
test1 \r\n
test2 \r\n
test2 \r\n
```

I commit the file and \r\n can be returned using git cat-file.

If i try to get the content via LibGit2Sharp i only get \n.

I tried GetContextString() and also the following with different encodings:

```
    Blob blob = (Blob)treeEntry.Target;

    string content;
    using (var tr = new StreamReader(blob.GetContentStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        content = tr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetContentText()` won't perform any cr/lf substitution by default. Only the overloads accepting a `FilteringOptions` would allow this.

`GetContextText()` will only try to apply a default UTF8 to UTF16 Encoding conversion. This can be overridden by explicitly passing the encoding of the `Blob` content.

> Is there a possibility to get the real content without any changes?

Use `GetContentStream()`. It will return the raw content of the blob.

You can take a peek at the **[BlobFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BlobFixture.cs)** test suite to get a better understanding of those methods and their behavior.

> This file contains "\r".

Considering the explanation above, there are huge chances that the blob actually contains this character in the git object database. You could double check this through the **[git cat-file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file)** command and a hex editor.

**Note:** Would you have found a bug in the library, please raise an issue in the **[bug tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)** with a repro case. We'll happily fix it!

Comment: I have this filecontent: 
"test \r\n 
test2 \r\n 
test3 \r\n"

I tried GetContentText() and also GetContentStream() with different encodings. Both return only \n at the end of a line. Inside the repository the \r\n exists.

Comment: Provided you don't pass a `FilteringOptions` parameter, `GetContentStream()` delegates to libgit2 **[git_blob_rawcontent()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/4c219cf64868d1b3fc2c5df0bbf803b40c6e4cef/include/git2/blob.h#L89)** which doesn't perform crlf substitution. So if there's a CRLF in the repository, it will be returned as is and not transformed in a LF by this method. However, if you pass in a `FiletringOptions`, substitution will be performed, using the `hintpath`, according to the rules defined in .gitattributes file.

Comment: If the comment above doesn't help and you're still encountering an issue, could you please share a complete piece of code demonstrating it?

Comment: I edited the first post. This is how i was trying to get the content. and as I said, i also tried GetContentText() without passing any FilteringOptions...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ethomson: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/720

```
repo.Config.Set("core.autocrlf", false);
```

This line was the trick.

Comment: Although the amazing **[@edwardthomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson)** may have helped you solve your issue, I don't think **this** answer relates to the initial question. In your context, setting this config entry to false only prevents `Stage()` from dynamically converting CRLF to LF while inserting the blob in the object database. This setting has **no effect** on the way `GetContentText()` or `GetContentStream()` behave.

Comment: Thats right, your answer was the correct one conserning my initial question! And your answers always help me getting a better understanding of LibGit2Sharp. 
The problem was not GetContentText() or GetContentStream() as I was thinking. However this helped me solve my issue and it could be helpful for other people having the same problem. :)